# How to use std::any_of inside a class with lambda expression?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, lambda, std

I'm coding a small simulation in c++ with robots and I need to check if the robot are colliding. I implemented this function in my simulation's class:

```
bool World::isRobotColliding(Robot *r) {
    for (Robot *other_robot: robots) {
        double d = distance(r->getX(), r->getY(), other_robot->getX(), other_robot->getY());
        if ((r->getRadius() + other_robot->getRadius()) >= d) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

double World::distance(const double &x_1, const double &y_1, const double &x_2, const double &y_2) const {
    return sqrt((x_1 - x_2) * (x_1 - x_2) + (y_1 - y_2) * (y_1 - y_2));
}
```

Here my IDE suggested me to replace the for loop with the **std::any_of()** method. However, I was unable to use it properly. This is what I tried:

```
    return std::any_of(robots.begin(), robots.end(), [r, this](const Robot *&other_robot) {
        return
                (r->getRadius() + other_robot->getRadius())
                >=
                distance(r->getX(), r->getY(), other_robot->getX(), other_robot->getY());
    });
```

How can I use std::any_of() in my context?

Thank you

Comment: "This is what I tried" So what was the result? If there were compilation errors, please add them to your question.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. My guess is the getters are not marked `const`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're passing a pointer by reference?

Comment: Unrelated, but having a member function that only uses external variables (World::distance) is a bit of an anti-pattern. You could make it a free function.

Comment: "*However, I was unable to use it properly*" - why? What is stopping you? Please be more specific.

Comment: I would opt to add a method to `Robot` that takes another `Robot` as a parameter, eg: `r->distanceFrom(*other_robot)` and then let it use `distance()` internally (which itself should be `static` or free-floating). Then you don't need to capture `this` in the lambda. Then you can take this a step further by adding an `isCollidingWith()` method to `Robot`: `r->isCollidingWith(*other robot)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your advise,

The issue was the pointer passed by reference.

```
    return std::any_of(robots.begin(), robots.end(), [r, this](const Robot *other_robot) {
        double d = distance(r->getX(), r->getY(), other_robot->getX(), other_robot->getY());
        if(d == 0) return false;
        return
                (r->getRadius() + other_robot->getRadius())
                >=
                d;
    });
```

This snippet do exactly what I was expecting.

I needed to pass the first robot `r` in the context as well as `this`. I could have declared a distance function in my robot and ommiting the `this`.